# 802.11ac USB dongle support in Linux

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, arm, 802.1x

(cross-post from Network Engineering community)

Is it reasonable to expect to be able to get a 802.11ac dual-band USB wireless dongle to work correctly on Debian (wheezy) on an ARM platform (using one of 3.0.x, 3.4.x, 3.8.x kernel)?

I have been searching for a few weeks and cannot find any information as to whether this is a reasonable expection. There are many miniPCIe options (the ath10k driver is apparently pretty good), but my current setup doesn't support miniPCIe. I can move to a miniPCIe platform if absolutely required to, but I would like to put this matter to rest before I do that.

I have been told that there are currently 4 WiFi manufacturers that are producing ac chips: Qualcomm Atheros, Broadcomm, Intel and a company in Taiwan (Realtek, I assume?)

Broadcomm doesn't have ARM drivers, QCA doesn't have USB support, I've been told that Intel don't have USB drivers for Linux, and I have had no luck with the rtl8812au driver so far.

Comment: en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Linksys_WUSB6100M